# Inversion Of Control sample to build a security system in cross cutting layer

Tags: asp.net, wcf, dependency-injection, wif, unify

I'm searching example how to implement security system (I mean **authentication and authorization**) in **cross cutting layer** using Unify, WIF, WCF, ASP.NET MVC or ASP.NET or Silverlight...

Why we should always re-invent the wheel? :-)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this out : http://microsoftnlayerapp.codeplex.com/

There is all what you want

Comment: The URL is not working anymore which makes this answer now an empty answer.

Comment: Ok. I'll try to upgrade it today